# How to test weather click event is triggered on the <el-button> with vue-test-utils?

Tags: vue-test-utils, element-ui

I'm writing a project with `vue cli3` and `element-ui`,And i want to add unit test for my `.vue` files and `.js` files. I have bind a click event `openDialog` on the `<el-button>`, So i want to test if this click function is be called or not.But i'm not good at `vue-test-unit`,so All i tried is failed.

Here is my code:

```
<el-button
   type="mk-primary"
   icon="el-icon-coordinate"
   size="small"
   @click="openDialog"
   >filte</el-button>
```

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Orders from '@/views/orders/index.vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(ElementUI)

describe('Orders.vue', () => {
  it('button click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Orders, {
      localVue
    })
    const mockFn = jest.fn()
    const elButton = wrapper.find({ name: 'ElButton' })
    wrapper.setMethods({
      openDialog: mockFn
    })
    // wrapper.vm.$on('openDialog', mockFn)
    elButton.trigger('click')
    expect(mockFn).toBeCalled()
    expect(wrapper.find(elButton).exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the button click, you need to wait for `nextTick()` before asserting anything.

You should make your test function `async` and then you can use `await` on the `button.trigger()`. See the example in the [Vue-test-utils docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html).

For things you can't `await` on, you can explicitly `await Vue.nextTick()` or `wrapper.vm.$nextTick()`